# How to test model defaults in Rails with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I want to test that a new user when signed up, is not admin (as set by default: false in the migration). Here's my user_spec.rb so far:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

    before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

    subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:username) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }

  describe "When username is too short" do
    before { @user.username = 'ab' }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "When username is too long" do
    before { @user.username = 'a' * 26 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "Username is present" do
    before { @user.username = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

I've tried

```
it "should not be admin" do
  expect { @user.admin }.to be_false
end
```

but it returns:

```
   expected: false value
        got: #<Proc:0x007ffc4b544a58@"
```

I suspect this is because I'm running tests based off a factory but it would defeat the purpose of testing a default value if I explicitly put 'admin false' into the factory.

How can I test default model values? Should I run through a sign up with capybara and then test that user?

Comment: Is `admin` a boolean? If so, try `expect { @user.admin? }.to be_false`

Comment: @DamienRoche Admin is a boolean, and .admin? gives the same result

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. That's a strange return value. Try Pry, and add `binding.pry` just above that line, then query the `@user` instance and see what's going on.

Comment: @DamienRoche
Pry shows the full user model with the correct specifications as in my factories.rb. Admin is, as default, false. Thanks for trying to help btw.

`[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4>)> @user

=> #<User id: nil, email: "testuser@example.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, username: "testuser", admin: false>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `@user.admin` to expect as a parameter, not within a block, as in:

```
expect(@user.admin).to be(false)
```

Passing a block is intended for those cases where you want to evaluate the side effects of an operation, such as updating a database, raising an error, etc.